# Codeigniter - pagination - number links to show

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have implemented the pagination with the following configuration

```
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
$config['base_url'] = base_url()."jobs/?job=".$_GET['job']."&location=".$_GET['location'];
$config['total_rows'] = $totalCount;
$config['per_page'] = 10; 
$config['num_links']=15;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

This paginates fine with numbers showing from 1 to 16. Now when i click on 16th page, it shows numbers from 1-32 and so on. 
So it increases the number of page links instead of removing from start of the queue.

Where i am going wrong here?

Comment: I dont see any mistake in the above shared code. Would be  useful if u can even share the view part where u use create_links function

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same issue.I dont think any mistake in your code.I think its codeigniter pagination class issue.

I solved it by changing systems/libraries/Pagination.php file.

```
$start  = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;

$end    = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;
```

Commented above both lines and Added following lines.

```
$start  = ($this->cur_page >= $this->num_links) ? $this->cur_page - (((int)($this->num_links/2))-1) : 1;

$end    = ($this->cur_page >= $this->num_links) ? $this->cur_page + (int)($this->num_links/2) :$this->num_links;

if($end > $num_pages){
    $end = $num_pages;
}
```

So first it will show you

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

When you click on 15 page link, it will show you

8 9 10 11 12 13 14 **15** 16 17 18 19 20 21 22

When you click on 16 page link , it will show you

9 10 11 12 13 14 15 **16** 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

Comment: HI HBhadra can we do it without editing the system libraries. something like overriding the library. if it is possible please add an answer bellow it will be a good help

Answer (score -1):

there is no mistake there, i only advice you that:

```
$config['num_links']=15;
```

sets how many links you want to show, if they are `15,` you will see for example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 

then -> 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

and so on ...